# One login session_via_api_token redirect post login

Tags: javascript, tableau-api, onelogin

I was attempting to use Tableau online embeddable charts with OneLogin using the **session_via_api_token** method.

I am able to retrieve token from backend and pass it to frontend. As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37709781/onelogin-does-session-via-api-token-have-to-be-called-via-form-post), the only way to call session_via_api_token is to POST a form.

The issue I'm facing is, after the form's POST, I'm redirected to /apps page of OneLogin. Is there any way I can specify a return url, or make the default behavior to redirect to one particular page(of my domain) after login.

What I want to achieve is hit session_via_api_token request of onelogin and redirect it back to my custom reports page where I've embedded a couple of tableau reports.

Comment: have you solved that issue? I have a similar application that shows some charts from Tableau Online. I need the users to authenticate in my application with One login and then they must be authenticated in the embedded views from Tableau Online inside my website. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about the lack on detailed docs on this (it's coming!)

This endpoint relies on the `HTTP_REFERER` header being set and should redirect back to that URL.

Not sure what browser you're using, but that should be set automatically during the POST operation to our endpoint. It's worth noting that this does have to be done on the user's browser in order for us to establish an SSO session.

e.g. User's browser does a POST to our site with the token - We establish a session and set the cookies for our domain then we redirect back you your login 'facade'

To simplify things, we will be adding CORS support for this endpoint, and that work should be completing soon.